# The Fall Guy episode where Colt has a genuine close encounter with aliens

Tags: episode-identification, the-fall-guy

A recent discussion about *Close Encounters* prompted a memory from the 1980's.

An episode of *The Fall Guy* where Colt was investigating some place where they were faking alien spaceships to keep locals away (a very *Scooby-Doo* yarn!)

At the resolution when the bad guys were arrested Colt was asking how they'd rigged one particular incident where he'd been stopped by a spaceship, 
glowing light up above him, dead ignition etc.

Blank looks....it turned out (in *The Fall Guy* script) that he'd had a genuine close encounter at that point.

I've googled for 'Fall Guy Close Encounter' and 'Lee Majors meets alien' but no  luck.

Comment: It would be no worse than the final season of _The Six Million Dollar Man_ featuring Bigfoot.

Comment: I take back my first comment.

Comment: Your description vaguely resembles an X-Files episode in which some Air Force pilots pretending to be aliens are themselves confronted by an alien.

Comment: _"faking alien spaceships to keep locals away"_ I thought one fakes alien spaceships to get maximum tourist visitations. (Snet from a payphone at the George Adamski Inn)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yet it was the plot (featuring ghosts rather than aliens) of virtually every Scooby Doo episode.  It was a simpler (!), more innocent (!!) time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [Season 2, Epoisode 16](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0576169/) of *The Fall Guy*, episode title **"Spaced out"**. It aired on February 16, 1983.

According to IMDb:

> A small town starts believing a bunch of aliens robbed the local bank and start panicking, but Colt and the gang think otherwise.

There doesn't appear to be any mention of the "actual close encounter" gag in [this YouTube posting of the episode](https://youtu.be/rW1q6uox_hs)  -- the denouement, which begins at 43:15 after a crappy car chase, doesn't include the bad guys, it's just Colt explaining to the sheriff how they pulled it off. All the close encounters appear to be of the fake kind.

Answer (score 4):

Season 2 episode 16 "Spaced Out".

According to Wikipedia's ["List of *The Fall Guy* episodes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Fall_Guy_episodes):

> Colt and Howie are filming stunts for a war movie in a small, peaceful town when all the tranquility is shattered by "aliens" invading in a saucer-like UFO who rob the town's bank and kidnap Jody. Colt has his work cut out to unravel the mystery after he gets framed for the robbery and is detained by the town's Police.